# HSQLDB connection in Talend: User lacks privilege or object not found using

Tags: database, server, hsqldb, talend, privileges

I'm currently doing a comparision between Stambia and Talend. For this, I wanted to use the same data. So I tried to use the data available for Stambia tutorials. These are coming from an HSQL Database.

For this, I made a HSQLDB Sever with simples proprieties :

server.database.0 = file:hsqldb/demodb

server.dbname.0 = testdb

After that, I added the script whose coming from Stambia into my new database "demodb" :

```html
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB2467A82B33
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 10
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 1
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 200
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE SCHEMA DATAMART AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE SCHEMA HOTEL_DATAMART AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA DATAMART
CREATE MEMORY TABLE DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER(CUS_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL,CUS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,CUS_TITLE CHARACTER(32),CUS_NAME CHARACTER(50) NOT NULL,CUS_FORNAME VARCHAR(25),CUS_COMPANY VARCHAR(100),GEO_KEY_ID INTEGER,UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY(CUS_KEY_ID))
ALTER TABLE DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER ALTER COLUMN CUS_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 300
CREATE INDEX CUSTOMER_ID ON DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER(CUS_ID)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE DATAMART.DIM_GEOGRAPHY(GEO_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL,GEO_ZIP_CODE VARCHAR(6),GEO_CITY VARCHAR(50),GEO_DISTRICT_CODE VARCHAR(3),GEO_DISTRICT VARCHAR(50),GEO_REGION VARCHAR(50),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_GEOGRAPHY PRIMARY KEY(GEO_KEY_ID))
ALTER TABLE DATAMART.DIM_GEOGRAPHY ALTER COLUMN GEO_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 2
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_DIM_GEOGRAPHY ON DATAMART.DIM_GEOGRAPHY(GEO_ZIP_CODE,GEO_CITY)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE DATAMART.DIM_TIME(TIME_KEY_DAY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,TIME_DATE TIMESTAMP,TIME_MONTH_DAY NUMERIC(2),TIME_WEEK_DAY NUMERIC(1),TIME_DAY_NAME VARCHAR(15),TIME_MONTH NUMERIC(2),TIME_MONTH_NAME VARCHAR(15),TIME_QUARTER NUMERIC(1),TIME_YEAR NUMERIC(4),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_TIME PRIMARY KEY(TIME_KEY_DAY))
CREATE INDEX TIME_DAY ON DATAMART.DIM_TIME(TIME_DATE)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE DATAMART.DIM_DISCOUNT(DIS_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL,DIS_RANGE VARCHAR(35),DIS_MIN NUMERIC(3),DIS_MAX NUMERIC(3),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_DISCOUNT PRIMARY KEY(DIS_KEY_ID))
ALTER TABLE DATAMART.DIM_DISCOUNT ALTER COLUMN DIS_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 19
CREATE MEMORY TABLE DATAMART.DIM_PAYMENT_TYPES(PMT_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL,PMT_CODE VARCHAR(10),PMT_NAME VARCHAR(35),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_PAYMENT_TYPES PRIMARY KEY(PMT_KEY_ID))
ALTER TABLE DATAMART.DIM_PAYMENT_TYPES ALTER COLUMN PMT_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 9
CREATE MEMORY TABLE DATAMART.DIM_CHAMBER(CHB_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL,CHB_ID NUMERIC(10),CHB_NUMBER NUMERIC(4),CHB_FLOOR NUMERIC(2),CHB_BATH NUMERIC(1),CHB_SHOWER NUMERIC(1),CHB_WC NUMERIC(1),CHB_BED_NUMBER NUMERIC(2),CHB_PHONE_NUMBER CHARACTER(3),UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_CHAMBER PRIMARY KEY(CHB_KEY_ID))
ALTER TABLE DATAMART.DIM_CHAMBER ALTER COLUMN CHB_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 60
CREATE INDEX CHAMBER_ID ON DATAMART.DIM_CHAMBER(CHB_ID)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE DATAMART.FACT_BILLING(BIL_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL,BIL_ID NUMERIC(10,2),CUS_KEY_ID INTEGER,TIME_KEY_DAY VARCHAR(10),DIS_KEY_ID INTEGER,PMT_KEY_ID INTEGER,BIL_MONTANT NUMERIC(10,2),BIL_QTE NUMERIC(10),UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,CONSTRAINT PK_FACT_BILLING PRIMARY KEY(BIL_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BILLING_CUS FOREIGN KEY(CUS_KEY_ID) REFERENCES DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER(CUS_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BILLING_DIS FOREIGN KEY(DIS_KEY_ID) REFERENCES DATAMART.DIM_DISCOUNT(DIS_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BILLING_PMT FOREIGN KEY(PMT_KEY_ID) REFERENCES DATAMART.DIM_PAYMENT_TYPES(PMT_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BILLING_TIME FOREIGN KEY(TIME_KEY_DAY) REFERENCES DATAMART.DIM_TIME(TIME_KEY_DAY))
ALTER TABLE DATAMART.FACT_BILLING ALTER COLUMN BIL_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 8532
CREATE MEMORY TABLE DATAMART.FACT_BOOKING(BOK_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL,CUS_KEY_ID INTEGER,TIME_KEY_DAY VARCHAR(10),CHB_KEY_ID INTEGER,BOK_NP_PEOPLE NUMERIC(10),BOK_BOOKED NUMERIC(1),BOK_OCCUPIED NUMERIC(1),UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,CONSTRAINT PK_FACT_BOOKING PRIMARY KEY(BOK_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BOOKING_CHB FOREIGN KEY(CHB_KEY_ID) REFERENCES DATAMART.DIM_CHAMBER(CHB_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BOOKING_CUS FOREIGN KEY(CUS_KEY_ID) REFERENCES DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER(CUS_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BOOKING_TIME FOREIGN KEY(TIME_KEY_DAY) REFERENCES DATAMART.DIM_TIME(TIME_KEY_DAY))
ALTER TABLE DATAMART.FACT_BOOKING ALTER COLUMN BOK_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 43686
CREATE INDEX BOOK_CUS ON DATAMART.FACT_BOOKING(CUS_KEY_ID)
CREATE INDEX BOOK_TIM ON DATAMART.FACT_BOOKING(TIME_KEY_DAY)
SET SCHEMA HOTEL_DATAMART
CREATE SEQUENCE HOTEL_DATAMART.SEQ_GEO_KEY_ID AS INTEGER START WITH 1000
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_BEDROOM(BDR_ID NUMERIC(10),BDR_NUMBER NUMERIC(4),BDR_FLOOR NUMERIC(2),BDR_BATH NUMERIC(1),BDR_SHOWER NUMERIC(1),BDR_BAR NUMERIC(1),BDR_BED_COUNT NUMERIC(2),BDR_PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(3),BDR_TYPE VARCHAR(30),UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_BEDROOM PRIMARY KEY(BDR_ID))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_DISCOUNT(DIS_RANGE VARCHAR(35),DIS_MIN NUMERIC(3),DIS_MAX NUMERIC(3),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_DISCOUNT PRIMARY KEY(DIS_RANGE))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_GEOGRAPHY(GEO_KEY_ID NUMERIC(10),GEO_ZIP_CODE VARCHAR(6),GEO_CITY VARCHAR(50),GEO_STATE_CODE VARCHAR(3),GEO_STATE VARCHAR(50),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_GEOGRAPHY PRIMARY KEY(GEO_KEY_ID))
CREATE INDEX IDX_GEO_ZIP_CODE ON HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_GEOGRAPHY(GEO_ZIP_CODE)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_BIL_TYPE(BIL_TYPE_CODE VARCHAR(4),BIL_TYPE_NAME VARCHAR(35),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_BIL_TYPE PRIMARY KEY(BIL_TYPE_CODE))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_PAYMENT_TYPE(PMT_CODE VARCHAR(4),PMT_NAME VARCHAR(35),PMT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(35),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_PAYMENT_TYPE PRIMARY KEY(PMT_CODE))
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_TIME(TIME_KEY_DAY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,TIME_DATE TIMESTAMP,TIME_MONTH_DAY NUMERIC(2),TIME_WEEK_DAY NUMERIC(1),TIME_DAY_NAME VARCHAR(15),TIME_MONTH NUMERIC(2),TIME_MONTH_NAME VARCHAR(15),TIME_QUARTER NUMERIC(1),TIME_YEAR NUMERIC(4),CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_TIME PRIMARY KEY(TIME_KEY_DAY))
CREATE INDEX IX_TIME_DATE ON HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_TIME(TIME_DATE)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER(CUS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,CUS_TITLE VARCHAR(32),CUS_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,CUS_COMPANY VARCHAR(100),GEO_KEY_ID NUMERIC(10),CUS_VIP NUMERIC(1),UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY(CUS_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_DIM_CUSTOMER_GEO FOREIGN KEY(GEO_KEY_ID) REFERENCES HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_GEOGRAPHY(GEO_KEY_ID))
CREATE INDEX IDX_CUS_GEO_KEY_ID ON HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER(GEO_KEY_ID)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BILLING(BIL_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL,BIL_ID INTEGER,CUS_ID INTEGER,TIME_KEY_DAY VARCHAR(10),DIS_RANGE VARCHAR(35),PMT_CODE VARCHAR(4),BIL_AMOUNT NUMERIC(10,2),BIL_QTY NUMERIC(10,2),UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,CONSTRAINT PK_FACT_BILLING PRIMARY KEY(BIL_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BILLING_DIS FOREIGN KEY(DIS_RANGE) REFERENCES HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_DISCOUNT(DIS_RANGE),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BILLING_CUS FOREIGN KEY(CUS_ID) REFERENCES HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER(CUS_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BILLING_PMT FOREIGN KEY(PMT_CODE) REFERENCES HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_PAYMENT_TYPE(PMT_CODE),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BILLING_TIME FOREIGN KEY(TIME_KEY_DAY) REFERENCES HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_TIME(TIME_KEY_DAY))
ALTER TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BILLING ALTER COLUMN BIL_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 1
CREATE INDEX IDX_BIL_CUS_ID ON HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BILLING(CUS_ID)
CREATE INDEX IDX_BIL_DIS_RANGE ON HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BILLING(DIS_RANGE)
CREATE INDEX IDX_BIL_PMT_CODE ON HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BILLING(PMT_CODE)
CREATE INDEX IDX_BIL_TIME_KEY_DAY ON HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BILLING(TIME_KEY_DAY)
CREATE INDEX IDX_RANGE_AND_ID ON HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BILLING(BIL_ID,DIS_RANGE)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BOOKING(BOK_KEY_ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL,CUS_ID INTEGER,TIME_KEY_DAY VARCHAR(10),BDR_ID NUMERIC(10),BOK_PEOPLE NUMERIC(10),BOK_BOOKED NUMERIC(1),UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,CONSTRAINT PK_FACT_BOOKING PRIMARY KEY(BOK_KEY_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BOOKING_BDR FOREIGN KEY(BDR_ID) REFERENCES HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_BEDROOM(BDR_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BOOKING_CUS FOREIGN KEY(CUS_ID) REFERENCES HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER(CUS_ID),CONSTRAINT FK_FACT_BOOKING_TIME FOREIGN KEY(TIME_KEY_DAY) REFERENCES HOTEL_DATAMART.DIM_TIME(TIME_KEY_DAY))
ALTER TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BOOKING ALTER COLUMN BOK_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 1
CREATE INDEX IDX_BOK_BDR_ID ON HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BOOKING(BDR_ID)
CREATE INDEX IDX_BOK_TIME_KEY_DAY ON HOTEL_DATAMART.FACT_BOOKING(TIME_KEY_DAY)
CREATE MEMORY TABLE HOTEL_DATAMART.L1_DIM_TIME(L1_TIME_KEY_DAY VARCHAR(10),L2_TIME_DATE TIMESTAMP,L3_TIME_MONTH_DAY NUMERIC(2),L4_TIME_WEEK_DAY NUMERIC(1),L5_TIME_DAY_NAME VARCHAR(15),L6_TIME_MONTH NUMERIC(2),L7_TIME_MONTH_NAME VARCHAR(15),L8_TIME_QUARTER NUMERIC(1),L9_TIME_YEAR NUMERIC(4))
ALTER TABLE DATAMART.DIM_CUSTOMER ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DIM_CUSTOMER_GEO FOREIGN KEY(GEO_KEY_ID) REFERENCES DATAMART.DIM_GEOGRAPHY(GEO_KEY_ID)
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
ALTER SEQUENCE HOTEL_DATAMART.SEQ_GEO_KEY_ID RESTART WITH 209465
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
SET SCHEMA DATAMART
INSERT INTO DIM_CUSTOMER VALUES(200,1,'Monsieur','DUPONT                          ','Alain',NULL,1,'2013-06-04 11:43:21.211000')
INSERT INTO DIM_CUSTOMER VALUES(201,2,'Monsieur','MARTIN                          ','Marc','Transports MARTIN & fils',1,'2013-06-04 11:43:21.211000')
```

Now, I made an HSQLDB connection in Talend and I retrieve schema, so I have every tables of base_datamart in Talend.

I created a job with a source (delimited file) to charge my DIM_Discount table through a tMap.

But when I run the job, I get the error : Exception in component tHSQLDbOutput_1 (Load_DIM_DISCOUNT)

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DIM_DISCOUNT

I made research for about 2 days but I didn't find any solutions... if someone ever faced this problem, or has any idea for this, I would be really pleased.

Have a good day, thanks.

Comment: The usual reason for this sort of error is the JDBC URL of the connection points to a non-existing file: or mem: database, which is then created as empty.